# How to get the character at certain index of a string using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to make a function which performs some operations on strings. From my understanding, strings are character arrays. So by writing:

```
cout << name[0];
```

we print the first character written of an assumed string called 'name'.

In my function, I have to use pointers to perform all functions. My current approach is to make a pointer:

```
string *str=&name;
```

but when I try to print the character at specified index by writing:

```
cout << *str[0];
```

It doesn't compile, I'm not sure what is the problem. One solution would be to make a dynamic character array but I wanted to know if it is possible to get the character at certain indexes of strings using pointers?

Comment: "print an index" not sure i understand what exactly do you mean (given your example).

Comment: Use iterators not pointers

Comment: @Raxvan Say string name="abcd"; cout << name[0]; prints 'a'. How to do the same but using pointers?

Comment: @Raxvan It seems OP wants print the `char` at specified index.

Comment: @songyuanyao ah , i see now

Comment: You probably want [std::string::data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) .

Comment: It depends on what `string` is (e.g. is it `std::string`, or some `typedef` you have created.   However, roughly speaking, you need to do `cout << (*str)[0]`, not `cout << *str[0]` to allow for operator precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator[]` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator*`, so `*str[0]` is same as `*(str[0])`. `str[0]` returns a `std::string`, and calling `operator*` on `std::string` doesn't make sense.

Change it to `(*str)[0]`.